Aunt forces girl to marry her cousin
A father leaves his daughter to an aunt and go and tell her to return, but does not return . After several years her aunt forcing girl to marry her cousin who had taken care of before. After this move to another city where the girl falls in love with an old friend of her cousin with whom he kills . after a while begin to fear what they do and realize that the world learned what they did commit suicide on a lake.
It is in English, I saw it online I think in 2004 but I'm not sure about that. I think it's from 1985-1990.

Please add details like year, country\language and where you saw it (TV, DVD, theaters, Netflix...). I think I know what it is and this will make sure.

is in english, i saw it online and i think the year is 2004 but i'm not shure about that...

How old did it look? I'm asking because the story you're asking about has a ton of adaptations...

i think somwhere between 1985-1990,

thanks you so much, this is the movie, i've been looking for it for months

No problem, but please don't forget to mark it as 'solved' by clicking on the check mark.

You're describing the exact plot of Therese Raquin by Emile Zola. There were many adaptaions of it, but if it's in English & from the 80s, you might be after the 1980 mini-series with Brian Cox. There was also a recent adaptation (2013) with Elizabeth Olsen and Jessica Lange that was called In Secret. Here are some clips starring Alan Rickman from the mini-series:



